# Why would counting instances of vector values using sum() in R return NA

Tags: r

I imported the 2018 BRFSS data (available online) into R using the `read.xport()` and upon inspecting variable values, I'm unable to comprehend how r is handling the imported values. For example, in the imported data frame, the the class for the diabetes variable (DIABETE3) is numeric but when I attempt counting the specific values for each level using, say  `sum(BRFSS$DIABETE3==1)`, the result is `NA`. Here is a small vector for the first 20 values of DIABETE3 variable to demonstrate:

`diabetes <-c(3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3)`. If I use, `sum(BRFSS$DIABETE3==1)` to count instances of value `1`, the result is `NA`, but clearly that's not the case.

However, using `sum(is.na(BRFSS$DIABETE3))` returns the correct number of `NA` values. Using `table(BRFSS$DIABETE3)` also returns the proper frequency distribution for this variable.

Comment: Since you have `NA` values you need to exclude them in `sum`. Try `sum(BRFSS$DIABETE3==1, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks! I see the logic behind it now--- so the ```sum``` function is ideally adding logical values, ```TRUE``` or ```FALSE```  to ```NA```, which results to ```NA```!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are no `NA` values you can count instances of particular value by using

```
diabetes <- c(3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3)
sum(diabetes == 1)
#[1] 4
```

But if you have `NA`'s in your vector, this will fail

```
diabetes <- c(diabetes, NA)
sum(diabetes == 1)
#[1] NA
```

Because when you compare `NA` values with `==` it returns `NA` and to remove them you can set `na.rm` parameter as `TRUE`.

```
sum(diabetes == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 4
```